# The standalone icons on the Superbar™ display odd behavior in Firefox

Tags: bug, design

@Hakase found this minor graphical error on Firefox:

[image: bugger]

The bug in question can be traced to this bit of CSS:

```
.topbar .hidden-text { 
position: absolute; 
top: -200px; 
}
```

A quick solution suggests increasing the "top" value beyond the user's screen height/width like so:

```
.topbar .hidden-text { 
position: absolute; 
top: -100vw; /* vh is fine, too */
}
```

Alternatively, @Unihedron proposed a better solution relying purely on CSS, eliminating the need for the "hidden text" span. See the example for the standalone Inbox icon:

```
.topbar .topbar-icon.icon-inbox:after {
    content: "Inbox";
}
.topbar .topbar-icon {
    /* ...original line code... */
    text-indent: -100vw; /* Collapses the original line */
}
```

Comment: Another fully backwards compatible solution may be to add `display:none;` to the text element. Since screen readers usually chooses not to ignore text in `display:none;`, other sites take this approach in implementing blind mode as well.